# how to access object attribute that having name with space

Tags: python, excel

I used setattr method to set column names from an Excel file as attribute of object. However, these names include spaces like "Vendor name". How can I access the attribute like this?

```
for k in self.df.columns.values.tolist():
         setattr(self,k,self.df[k])
```

Comment: with `getattr`.

Comment: consider replacing the whitespace with an underscore or something while `setattr`ing

Answer (score 0):

With `getattr`, of course:

```
>>> class MyClass: pass
...
>>> my_object = MyClass()
>>> setattr(my_object, 'spaces are considered harmful', 42)
>>> getattr(my_object, 'spaces are considered harmful')
42
```

Or, you can always access the namespace of a custom class (where you haven't defined `__slots__`) by using the namespace directly:

```
>>> vars(my_object) is my_object.__dict__
True
>>> vars(my_object)
{'spaces are considered harmful': 42}
>>> my_object.__dict__
{'spaces are considered harmful': 42}
>>> vars(my_object)['spaces are considered harmful']
42
>>> my_object.__dict__['spaces are considered harmful']
42
```

Although really, instead of a custom class, it sounds like you want some container that is a sort of *mapping* from strings to other objects.